# Adding JQuery to CakePhp?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I want to use jquery in CakePhp 3.2.7. This is an error that I am receiving.

**Error**:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I added to **default.ctp** :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js') ?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First set remote files whitout http or https, like ``` -> script('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js')```, after add other jquery plugins, and last is your custom js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem:

I changed place two following lines :

1.`<?= $this->Html->script('index.js') ?>`

2.`<?= $this->Html->script('jquery.min') ?>`

to:

1.`<?= $this->Html->script('jquery.min') ?>`

2.`<?= $this->Html->script('index.js') ?>`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?= $this -> Html -> script('yourFile.js') ?> /yourFile.js must be in your webroot/js folder
```

If you don´t want to have a jquery.js file in your project, don´t use the helper and just put the url route to script in your default layout

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use html helper to set local and remote assets whitout any problem

Comment: @Salines how you can use html Helper to set remote js file?? give me an example pleasse! I´m open to learn all days

Comment: @Salines it´s true! its works with remote assets, i checked it at this moment, I apologize for the confused response :(

Comment: @Digipng what not working? remote jquery file not load or you have js error?

Comment: @Digipng are you tried to download the jquery file and put it in webroot/js folder?

Comment: @Jacek B Budzyñski  I have a jquery file in webroot/js . I used from <?= $this->Html->script('jquery') ?> and <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> . and there is error: $ is not defined

Comment: @Digipng is it possible to show us your complete file default.ctp? A few minutes ago I try booth options and in my projects it.s work fine.